# Sets $[a,b]$ not homeomorphic to $(a,b)$ on the real line with standard topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I've seen a proof to this statement using connectivity.

It goes something like this: if two sets have homeomorphism between them, connectivity of one implies the connectivity of the other. That's fine.

Now the proof says that since $[a,b]$  has $2$ points we can remove and it will still be connected (true) while $(a,b)$ has none (also true).

What I can't figure out is how that proves they aren't homeomorphic?

Comment: Not using connectivity: One set is compact. the other not

Comment: Points like you desdrive are called "cut points". Prove that a homeomorphism sends cut points to cut points.

Comment: Suppose you have a set $X$ with a topology $\tau\subset{\cal P}(X)$. If $Y$ is another set and there is a bijection $X\to Y$, then there is an induced bijection $\tau\to\rho$ with $\rho\subset{\cal P}(Y)$. This is called transport of structure. Every homeomorphism of topological spaces arises in this way: they are *the same space*, just with the elements of the space labelled differently, and hence the elements of the open sets also relabelled accordingly. Since they are the same space, they should have the same topological properties, such as existence of a cut point.

Comment: @user251257 Can you prove your statement? I know closed and bounded sets are compact in Rn but how tt prove () aren't?

Comment: Heine-Borel says a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ is compact if and **only if** it is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a set $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ via a homeomorphism $f$ and we remove a point $x$ from $X$, then $X\setminus \{x\}$ is also homeomorphic to $Y\setminus \{f(x)\}$.

Therefore, if $[a,b]$ is homeomorphic to $(a,b)$, there must exist some point $y\in (a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\setminus \{y\}$ is homeomorphic to $[a,b]\setminus \{a\} = (a,b]$.

But obviously, such a point does not exist (because of the arguments above), so there is no homeomorphism.

---

This kind of reasoning is very common not only in topology, but in mathematics in general. In order to prove $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$, you need to find some property $X$ which translates through homeomorphisms (compactness, connectedness, $T_1$, $T_2,\dots$) and then prove that $X$ has the property and $Y$ does not.

Comment: One should note however that $y$ is not arbitrary. It should be $y=f(x)$ where $f\colon X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Agreed. Fixed.